# Finding the max(latest) date out of a column of dates then grouping them by employee

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime, max

#### Importing the data frame

`df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users")`

#### Printing the list of employees usernames

`print (df['AssignedTo'])`

Returns:

`Out[4]:
    0        vaughad
    1        channln
    2        stalasi
    3         mitras
    4         martil
    5          erict
    6          erict
    7        channln
    8           saia
    9        channln
    10       roedema
    11       vaughad`

#### Printing The Dates

Returns:

`Out[6]:
    0      2015-11-05
    1      2016-05-27
    2      2016-04-26
    3      2016-02-18
    4      2016-02-18
    5      2015-11-02
    6      2016-01-14
    7      2015-12-15
    8      2015-12-31
    9      2015-10-16
    10     2016-01-07
    11     2015-11-20`

#### Now I need to collect the latest date per employee?

#### I have tried:

`MaxDate = max(df.FilledEnd)`

#### But this just returns one date for all employees.

So we see multiple employees in the data set with different dates, in a new column named "LatestDate" I need the latest date that corresponds to the employee, so for "vaughad" in a new column it would return "2015-11-20" for all of "vaughad" records and in the same column for username "channln" it would return "2016-5-27" for all of "channln" latest dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [*group your data*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) first, using [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby), after which you can produce aggregate values, like the maximum date in the `FilledEnd` series:

```
df.groupby('AssignedTo')['FilledEnd'].max()
```

This produces a series, with `AssignedTo` as the index, and the latest date for each of those employees as the values:

```
>>> df.groupby('AssignedTo')['FilledEnd'].max()
AssignedTo
channln    2016-05-27
erict      2016-01-14
martil     2016-02-18
mitras     2016-02-18
roedema    2016-01-07
saia       2015-12-31
stalasi    2016-04-26
vaughad    2015-11-20
Name: FilledEnd, dtype: object
```

If you wanted to add those max dates values back to the dataframe, use `groupby(...).transform()` with `numpy.max` instead, so you get a series with the same indices:

```
df['MaxDate'] = df.groupby('AssignedTo')['FilledEnd'].transform(np.max)
```

This adds in a `MaxDate` column:

```
   AssignedTo   FilledEnd     MaxDate
0     vaughad  2015-11-05  2015-11-20
1     channln  2016-05-27  2016-05-27
2     stalasi  2016-04-26  2016-04-26
3      mitras  2016-02-18  2016-02-18
4      martil  2016-02-18  2016-02-18
5       erict  2015-11-02  2016-01-14
6       erict  2016-01-14  2016-01-14
7     channln  2015-12-15  2016-05-27
8        saia  2015-12-31  2015-12-31
9     channln  2015-10-16  2016-05-27
10    roedema  2016-01-07  2016-01-07
11    vaughad  2015-11-20  2015-11-20
```

Comment: so now that I have that, how would I take the date for each employee and cast it to a new column that corresponds to each employee? Since an employee is mentioned several times, I want the max date displayed in a new column that corresponds to the employee in the row. Thank you for your help.